# Powershell - copy file from various locations with different domain credentials

Tags: powershell, foreach

I'm looking for a powershell solution to copy a given filename.txt from several server unc-paths with different domain login credentials to a given folder - as well as renaming the filenames based on a list of names (or case/if-stmt) and exporting the subfolder names of each server path to a csv with the server- and filename as columns.

Below is the code I used for **one** server - I just added a few server- and filenames.

Can you help me to make this work?

I use Powershell Version 4.

Example:

```
$serverNames = @(
    "\\serverA\folderA";
    "\\serverB\folderA";
    "\\serverC\folderA";
)
$fileNames = @(
    "fileServerA";
    "fileServerB";
    "fileServerC";
)

foreach ($element in $serverNames) {
Try {

 If (Test-Path Q:){
 Remove-PSDrive -Name "Q" -Force

 # two server paths are in a different domain, 
 # so I need a case or if-stmt to pass login credentials
 New-PSDrive -Name "Q" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $element -Credential
}
else{
  New-PSDrive -Name "Q" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $element -Credential
    }

    #copy filename.txt (always the same name)
    robocopy $element\SubFolder\ C:\temp\ filename.txt /R:2 /W:3 /XO 

    #rename filename.txt according to fileName
    Move-Item C:\temp\filename.txt C:\temp\$name.xml -Force

    #scan dir and write foldernames (only "first" child folders) to .txt file with the according serverName AND fileName as columns
    dir -Directory \\serverA\folderA | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you build an array of objects containing all those details? Then you could loop each one individually with their own credentials.

```powershell
$servers = @()
$servers += [pscustomobject]@{
    name = "\\serverA\folderA"
    files = "fileServerA"
    creds = Get-Credential
}
$servers += [pscustomobject]@{
    name = "\\serverB\folderA"
    files = "fileServerB"
    creds = Get-Credential
}
$servers += [pscustomobject]@{
    name = "\\serverC\folderA"
    files = "fileServerC"
    creds = Get-Credential
}

$servers | ForEach-Object{
    #.... Stuff here
}
```

If the servers share credential then you could declare credential sets outside the declarations shown to use them multiple times. Inside the loop you can now call `New-PSDrive` and use the parameter `-Credential $_.creds`